# What permission set does the AppDomain CreateInstance required?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, code-access-security

I have the following **code**,

```
appDomain.CreateInstance(
                assemblyName, typeName, false, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null, new object[] { language, encoding }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null).Unwrap()
```

I am getting this **error**,

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
```

**StackTrace**,

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.IsolatedTemplateService..ctor(Language language, Encoding encoding, IAppDomainFactory appDomainFactory) in c:\Users\XX\Downloads\RazorEngine-850082854d1d046d27fb92af8849a2522c2a0246\RazorEngine-850082854d1d046d27fb92af8849a2522c2a0246\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\IsolatedTemplateService.cs:line 72
   at RazorEngine.Templating.IsolatedTemplateService..ctor(Language language, Encoding encoding, Func`1 appDomainFactory) in c:\Users\XX\Downloads\RazorEngine-850082854d1d046d27fb92af8849a2522c2a0246\RazorEngine-850082854d1d046d27fb92af8849a2522c2a0246\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\IsolatedTemplateService.cs:line 91
   at RazorEngine.Templating.IsolatedTemplateService..ctor(Func`1 appDomainFactory) in c:\Users\XX\Downloads\RazorEngine-850082854d1d046d27fb92af8849a2522c2a0246\RazorEngine-850082854d1d046d27fb92af8849a2522c2a0246\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\IsolatedTemplateService.cs:line 56
   at TemplateGenerator.Generate(String template, Object model, Int32 productsPerPage) in e:\TFS WorkSpaces\XX\XXWeb App\Solution\Helpers\TemplateGenerator.cs:line 42
```

**SecurityException.Demanded,**

```
{<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" Unrestricted="true"/>}
```

**SecurityException.GrantedSet,**

```
<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1">
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Unrestricted="true"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Flags="Execution"/>
</PermissionSet>
```

Comment: What is the type you try to create an instance from?

Comment: Does your type inherit `MarshalByRef` class?

Comment: A simple class. @SergeyLitvinov, No

Comment: It should inherit it, because otherwise marshaling between two different AppDomains won't work. In that case it will try to serialize\deserialize your type from appDomain to current AppDomain

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov, I am not marshaling between domain.

Comment: You use AppDoman just for creation object? It's a bit strange for me, because the only thing that will happens in AppDomain is creation, and then it will try to serialize it. Are you trying to make Sandbox AppDomain?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov, Actually I am debugging RazorEngine. See my previous quesion.

Comment: Try setting permissions specified here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c7zbfty(v=vs.110).aspx  (.NET Framework security section)